# Transfer variable value to html using ModelMap

Tags: java, spring

this method opens a page when clicking on a link in which I want the value of the message attribute, I did not add the servlet and jsp, how can I display it? my html is empty

```
@GetMapping("/activate/{code}")
public String activate(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String code) {

    boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
    if (isActivated) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "User Successfully activated");
        System.out.println("Successfully");
    } else System.out.println("Activation code not found");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Activation code not found");
    return "verificationPage";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `RedirectAttributes`

```
@GetMapping("/activate/{code}")
public String activate(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String code, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs) {

    redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", "Here is your message");
}
```